# Output sorting algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

I want to use sorting for array of number, here the code:

```
package SortAlgorithm;

public abstract class Sort {
    abstract int[] sort(int[] array);

    void swap(int a,int b){
        int temp;
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    static void print(int[] array){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}

public class SelectionSort extends Sort{

    private int indexMin = 0;

    public int[] sort(int[] arrNum){
        int[] numbers = arrNum;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            indexMin = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++){
                if(numbers[j] < numbers[indexMin]){
                    indexMin = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[indexMin];
            numbers[indexMin] = temp;
        }

        return numbers;
    }
}

public class MSorting {

    static int[] hasilSort;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] arrNum = {4,7,5,9,1};
        Sort.print(arrNum);
        System.out.println();

        SelectionSort sortSatu = new SelectionSort();
        hasilSort = sortSatu.sort(arrNum);
        Sort.print(hasilSort);
        System.out.println();
        Sort.print(arrNum);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the output is weird. This is the output I get:

```
4 7 5 9 1
1 4 5 7 9 
1 4 5 7 9
```

But I want the output like this:

```
4 7 5 9 1 
1 4 5 7 9 
4 7 5 9 1
```

What's wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by doing `int[] numbers = arrNum;` in your sort method you are assigning the reference of `arrNum` to `numbers`, which by swaping the values for the array `numbers` essentially let´s you swap the values for `arrNum` aswell. That´s logical, because they refer to the same `int` array instance.

you should copy the value into `numbers` if you don´t want to change the original array. this can be done by simply looping over `arrNum` and assigning each value to `numbers` for each respective position like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[arrNum.length];
for(int i = 0;i<arrNum.length;++i) {
    numbers[i] = arrNum[i];
}
```

or you use the implementation to copy arrays provided by the `system` class.

```
int[] numbers = new int[arrNum.length];
System.arraycopy(arrNum, 0, numbers, 0, arrNum.length);
```

Comment: but, when i change the swap process in Selection Sort with swap that inherits from class Sort, it can't swap,, why??

Comment: @diaz because java is `pass-by-value`. The one with the array did only work due to it beeing an array, and arrays are treated as objects. But when you reassign an `int` nothing will change for the variables passed by the caller